# How to restore a MySQL database from Azure blob/store to Azure Database for MySQL flexible server

Tags: azure-storage, azure-database-mysql

According to this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-migrate-dump-restore

You can:

> Copy the backup files to an Azure blob/store and perform the restore from there, which should be a lot faster than performing the restore across the Internet.

However there is no information on how to actually achieve this.

I created an Azure storage account, uploaded a large .SQL file, but I'm not sure how I would go about importing this using `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

**To achieve your scenario, please try the below:**

To **restore** **`MySql`** Database for **`MySql`** flexible server, you can run the below command from this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-migrate-dump-restore#restore-your-mysql-database-using-command-line-or-mysql-workbench):

```bash
mysql -h [hostname] -u [uname] -p[pass] [db_to_restore] < [backupfile.sql]
```

**For **`MySql`** flexible server:**

```bash
$ mysql -h testserver.mysql.database.azure.com -u admin -p testdb <testdb_backup.sql
```

To create a **backup** file using **`mysqldump`** you can try the below command from this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-migrate-dump-restore#create-a-backup-file-from-the-command-line-using-mysqldump):

```bash
$ mysqldump --opt -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] > [backupfile.sql]
```

For more in detail, please refer **below** links:

[Backup Azure Database for MySQL to a Blob Storage by Bashar Hussein](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-mysql-blog/backup-azure-database-for-mysql-to-a-blob-storage/ba-p/803830)

[Backup and restore SQL Server to Azure Blob storage by Bijay Kumar Sahoo](https://sqlserverguides.com/backup-and-restore-sql-server-to-azure-blob-storage/)